# Cannot refer to other within method utilizing self - python 3.6

Tags: python-3.x, methods, self

I have been going at this question and i cant seem to wrap my head around the **add**() portion of it. if any one could help me out and explain it to me that would be much appreciated. especially with the other parameter. The actual question is within the Docstring of the methods. I beleive the ***str***(self): method is correct and the **init**(self,m,b) method is correct also but if not please correct me.

```
class LinearPolynomial():
    def __init__(self, m, b):
        self.m = m
        self.b = b

    def __str__(self):
        """
        Returns a string representation of the LinearPolynomial instance
        referenced by self.

        Returns
        -------
        A string formatted like:

        mx + b

        Where m is self.m and b is self.b
        """
        string= '{}x + {}'
        return string.format(self.m,self.b)

    def __add__(self, other):
        """
        This function adds the other instance of LinearPolynomial
        to the instance referenced by self.

        Returns
        -------
        The sum of this instance of LinearPolynomial with another
        instance of LinearPolynomial. This sum will not change either
        of the instances reference by self or other. It returns the
        sum as a new instance of LinearPolynomial, instantiated with
        the newly calculated sum.
        """
        Cm= other.m + self.m
        Cb = other.b + self.b
        string= '{}x + {}'
        return string.format(Cm,Cb)
```

The expected results are within the docstring of the methods.

Comment: Thanks for the edit Patrick!

Comment: What unexpected result are you getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create and return a new `LinearPolynomial` object, not a string. Your method should also check the type of the other operand and return the `NotImplemented` value if it is not a `LinearPolynomial`

```
def __add__(self, other):
    if not isinstance(other, LinearPolynomial):
        return NotImplemented
    Cm = other.m + self.m
    Cb = other.b + self.b
    return LinearPolynomial(Cm, Cb)
```

Comment: Thanks so much Patrick this actually makes a lot of sense! I didn't realize i could just refer back to the original method within return.